# ASP.NET help (consuming a public Web Service)

Tags: c#, asp.net, spotify

So I am new to creating ASP.NET, and I have to build a asp.net site using Spotify. Essentially, I have to ask the user to enter an artist name and use Spotify's endpoints  (https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/endpoint-reference/) to fetch and return the data. Then I have to parse the data and sort it into a table to sort the artist name, album, year, etc. So, as a reference I just want to know where should I go to learn how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The API you referenced is a rest API, which means as long as you can send a HTTP request and consume the response, you can work with the API.

You can use the HTTPClient object to do that, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781239.aspx) for examples of how to send a get request. It boils down to:

```
var  httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = httpClient.GetAsync(".../v1/albums/myalbumid");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

*Note the code snippet above uses the Async version of things, you can use the non-async if you prefer.*

you can then use [json.net](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) to parse responseBodyAsText and use [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to read the json attributes you are interested in, or alternatively you could define a strongly typed object that corresponds to the response you would get from spotify and deserialzie directly to that object.

You can insert the data into your db using a stored procedure or an INSERT statement:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TABLE OR RUN A SPROC", con)){
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AlbumName", myAlbumName");
    con.open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

For your application framework (assuming it is web based) you can use [Web Forms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms) or [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) (rest) or [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc), whichever you prefer.

Hope this helps get you started.

*Please not the code provided here is only an example and will most likely contain errors and will not compile.*

Comment: https://github.com/djhmateer/githubscratch/tree/master/WebApplicationSpotify  this is a working version of just the call to spotify (non async)